# Notation or matrix operations for product of all elements in a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors, products

Let $a=\left[\begin{array}.a_1\\\vdots\\a_n\end{array}\right]$ be a vector.
Is there any standard notation for or any simple matrix operations that gives the product $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i ?$$

Comment: There's no matrix you can apply to get that product because the mapping $(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \rightarrow a_1 \cdot \cdots \cdot a_n$ is not linear.  You could try looking at $(\log a_1, \ldots, \log a_n)$ instead.  Then $\sum_i \log a_i = \log \prod_i a_i$.

Comment: It is the determinant of the diagonal matrix that you can get with this vector: $P = det(diag(A))$. Not sure that it is very helpful

Comment: yes, that was exactly what I was looking for, $\prod_ia_i=\det(\textbf{diag}(A))$, Thanks! @Damien

Answer (score 4):

If $D = \text{diag}(a) = \text{diag}(a_1,\dots,a_n)$, then 
$$
\det D = \prod_{i = 1}^n a_i.
$$